# Get cwd from terminal (bash) in ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I have a Rakefile in `/Users/dru/repo` and I want to run a rake task from the current working directory of the terminal.

So for example if I'm cd'd into `/Users/dru/repo/cookbooks/mybook` and I run `rake cwd`, I want to get the directory I'm cd'd into and not `/Users/dru/repo`, which is what's currently happening because that's where the Rakefile lives.

What I'm trying to do is run `knife cookbook test mybook`.

```
desc "Run rspec from terminal's cwd"
task :cwd do
  cwd = (/[^\/]+$/).match(Dir.pwd)
  sh "bundle exec knife cookbook test #{cwd}"
end
```

This runs `bundle exec knife cookbook test repo` but I want to run `bundle exec knife cookbook test mybook` if I'm cd'd into that directory.

## What I ended up doing

Matt Brictson's answer gave me an idea of the solution I was looking for and ended up working perfectly.

In my create_project task I added:

```
File.open("#{TOPDIR}/cookbooks/#{args.name}/Rakefile", "w") do |rake|
  rake.puts "load '../../Rakefile'"
end
```

Which places a Rakefile at the root of each cookbook that loads the Rakefile from the root of the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `rake`, as you discovered, is to search for a `Rakefile` and then change into the directory where the Rakefile is located. You can see the code that does this in [rake/application.rb](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/v10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb#L687)

To avoid this, you can run rake in "system wide" mode using the `--system` flag. This will alter rake's behavior so that it no longer searches for a Rakefile. Instead, it will look for files named `*.rake` inside the global rakefiles location, which is usually `~/.rake/`.

Therefore:

1. Define your `:cwd` task in a file located at `~/.rake/cwd.rake`.
2. Run `rake --system cwd`

This should run the `:cwd` task within your current working directory.

Comment: This gives me an idea to just add a Rakefile on project creating with a single line `load '../../Rakefile'`. I've tried it and it works but do you see any potential downsides to this?

Comment: That should work fine, too. The downside is that it is a little extra setup you have to do when you create a new project. Also, if you use a relative path like `../../Rakefile` then it could break if you ever move your project to a different location on the filesystem. Might be better to use `File.expand_path("~/Rakefile")`.

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand you then I guess you can pass your current location as param. Like this:

```
desc "Run rspec from terminal's cwd"
task :cwd, [:arg1] do |t, args|
  cwd = (/[^\/]+$/).match(args[:arg1])
  sh "bundle exec knife cookbook test #{cwd}"
end
```

Then run from shell: `bundle exec rake "cwd[$(pwd)]"`

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Dru Oh, that's ok! The question just has become more interesting. But next time you should put as more info in your question as you can. For example what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: My mistake. I'll make sure I do that. I want to avoid this because it's hard to type each time and looks ugly.